# How to transfer two columns of IDs into two columns of Names using mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns of IDs like this :

[image]

How do i covert it into two columns with their corresponding names using MySQL?

[image]

Comment: Please consider including sample table definitions with sample data, and clarify the expected output. As currently written, the question makes it appear like you want the output to appear like the second image. Its better to post actual characters than images. Sample tables, sample data, a description of the expected output along with an example that demonstrates it. That makes it much more likely your question will attract answers, ratter than downvotes. (If you don't take time or care to explain the question, its less likely that someone will take the time or care to answer it.)

Answer (score 0):

Without table definitions, we're just guessing:

We'll assume that the two column table is named `first_table` and contains columns named `col1` and `col2`. (I resisted my Dr.Seuss-like temptation to name them `thing1` and `thing2`.)

We'll assume that there's a second table, unfortunately named `second_table`, that contains columns `rid` and `name`.

We can use a query like this:

```
SELECT t.rid
     , s.name
  FROM ( SELECT t1.col1 AS rid
           FROM first_table t1
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t2.col2 
           FROM first_table t2
       ) t
  LEFT
  JOIN second_table s
    ON s.rid = t.rid
 ORDER
    BY t.rid
```

The inline view `t` gets the contents of `col1` into a set, and then concatenates a second set to it, the contents of `col2`. This gives us a single list of values.

We wrap that query into a set of parens, to turn it into an inline view (or *derived table* if we use the MySQL vernacular.)

We can then do a join operation to do the lookup of name, matching on the `rid` column.

This isn't the only way to do it, there are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

Comment: Thank you Spencer! But I still wanna keep the pari-wise information from the first table. Basically, question is how to convert a table with two columns ID into a table with two columns of Name? using union will lose that pair information

Comment: @BruceYan:  including an *example* of the expected output in the question would really help illustrate this part of the specification. Chekc the question, as if you didn't know what was being asked.  That second image appears to be an illustration of the expected output...it's  "two columns" and "with their corresponding names".

Comment: @BruceYan: Rather than posting *images* consider setting up a SQLFildde  http://sqlfiddle.com/  with sample table definitions and sample data. You are much more likely to attract answers to your question.